# how to send value in proctractor of date field

Tags: javascript, html, selenium, protractor

This is my html

```
<input id="filter-datepicker" type="daterange"ranges="ranges" 
      class="form-control date-picker" placeholder="Select Date Range" name="sensorDetails.date"
      ng-model="myDateRange" ranges="ranges" required />
```

**This is my proctor js**

```
var date = element(by.model('myDateRange'))
date.sendKeys("2015-05-04 - 2015-09-30")
```

This is not working,I cannot send the value.

Comment: What exactly is not working? Do you get an exception and if so, can you post it?

Comment: What kind of date range picker are you using? Have you created it or have you used an existing one from bootstrap or angular?

Comment: I've ran into a similar issue in FireFox and I had to click on the field first then use sendKeys. Try the following:

`element(by.id('filter-datepicker')).click();`
`element(by.id('filter-datepicker')).sendKeys('2015-05-04 - 2015-09-30');`

Comment: yes I did that only but it is taking the date but appending with today's date like
2015-09-232015-05-04 - 2015-09-30

Answer (score 0):

you can try

```
executeScript("document.getElementById('someElem').value = '2011-11-11';");
```

Comment: yes I did that only but it is taking the date but appending with today's date like 2015-09-232015-05-04 - 2015-09-30

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('filter-datepicker').val('2011-11-11');
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Can you explain a bit about the code you've posted? It might help OP or future users more.

Comment: yes I did that only but it is taking the date but appending with today's date like 2015-09-232015-05-04 - 2015-09-30